# How to initialize a bitset type all bits to 1

Tags: c++, std-bitset

I know set() function for a already constructed bitset object, but I need a constructed bitset which all bits are 1. The situation is a default function parameter.
for example:

```
void bar(std::bitset<100> flags = X) {
}
```

what X should be, -1 may works for first 64 bits, but not all.

Comment: i think reverse logic should be a way, which 0 means set, 1 means not set.

Comment: But why don't just write std::bitset<100>().set() instead X?

Comment: I need a default parameter, i want to omit the argument when call the function bar()

Comment: This worked for me (tested on VS2012, with disabled language extension): void bar(std::bitset<100> flags = std::bitset<100>().set() ) {
 std::cout << flags;
} If this really some non-standart extension (don't think so, but cannot check now), you can use global constant, as a last resolt.

Comment: it also works for gcc 4.5.3(cygwin), great!

Comment: Alternatively `flags = ~std::bitset<100>()`

Answer (score 19):

```
std::bitset<100> bs;
bs.set();
```

Or combine into 1 statement:

```
std::bitset<100> bs  = std::bitset<100>().set();
```

In C++11:

```
auto bs = std::bitset<100>{}.set();
```

Edit: or better use `std::move` to avoid copy because `set` return lvalue reference `bitset&`:

```
auto bs = std::move(std::bitset<100>{}.set());
```

---

Performance of `operator ~`, `flip()` and `set()`:

```
std::bitset<100> bs;
clock_t t;
t = clock();
for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    bs = std::bitset<100>().set();
}
t = clock() - t;
std::cout << "Using set() cost: " << t << " clicks." << std::endl;

t = clock();
for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    bs = ~std::bitset<100>();
}
t = clock() - t;
std::cout << "Using ~ cost: " << t << " clicks." << std::endl;

t = clock();
for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    bs = std::bitset<100>().flip();
}
t = clock() - t;
std::cout << "Using flip cost: " << t << " clicks." << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
Using set() cost: 59 clicks.
Using ~ cost: 104 clicks.
Using flip cost: 75 clicks.
```

Surprisingly `set()` is much faster than `operator ~` and `flip`

Comment: `~` requires the CPU to read, modify, write.  `set` only requires a write, and they're both so fast that it actually makes a minuscule difference.

Comment: I don't think I've ever before seen code where the read made any performance difference!  impressive.

Comment: @MooingDuck I just read from reference that `~` actually makes a copy of the original bitset (return `bitset` instead of `bitset&`) so that's much slower. Similar operation `flip()`, however, modifies the original bitset and return reference, but it is still slower than `set()` with smaller difference

Comment: Is "bitset<100> bs  = bitset<100>().set();" efficient? since it is creating a temporary bitset object with 100 bits set and then its copying the same to bs. Is my understanding correct and if so is it efficient(compared to bitset<100> bs; bs.set())?

Comment: The Edit is not really useful as `bitset` does not benefit from move. Even if it did, it would have been done automatically in that case.

Comment: @user362515 agree, it was already an rvalue

Answer (score 7):

You can use `std::bitset<100> = std::bitset<100>(std::string(100, '1'))` but it's a bit ugly imo

Comment: I actually like that compared to the other options.

Comment: Except it will be slow.